# 3 niveis de dados CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Suponhamos que tenho as seguintes tabaelas

**produtos**

**marcas**

**fabricantes**

Então terei 3 models. Um para cada tabela. Cada model é configurado com o seguinte esquema:

**Model de produtos** -> belongsTo: marcas
**Model de marcas** -> belongsTo: fabricantes

Até aí apenas modelei a questão dos dados.

Agora se eu fizer o seguinte comando em um controller qualquer, supondo que meu model da tabelas produtos se chame **ProdutoModel** e meu de marcas **MarcaModel**

```
$this->Produto->find('first')
```

vou receber algo como:

```
array(
    [Product] => array(
        // dados dos produtos
        [Brand] => array(
            // dados das marcas
        )
    )
)
```

Ou seja, não veio os dados do fabricante, mesmo ele pertencendo ao model Marca.

Tem algum modo desse array de resultado ser de 3 níveis, ou seja o model de Fabricantes vir junto dentro do array de Marcas?

> Algo que seja NATIVO do CakePHP, sem precisar fazer duas consultas e
>   mescla-las

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`Containable`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) para isso. Ficaria assim:

```
$this->Produto->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->Produto->contain('Marca' => array('Fabricante'));
$produto = $this->Produto->find('first');
```

Como indicado na documentação dessa classe, você consegue um resultado semelhante com o atributo [`recursive`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) do *Model*, mas o *Containable* é recomendado quando você possui associações complexas. Eu prefiro desta forma, pois faço uma consulta mais "personalizada".

E após utilizar, você pode dar *unload*:

```
$this->Produto->Behaviors->unload('Containable');
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui rapidamente e após fazer isso pontuo e até deixo sua resposta como melhor